# Error in tutorial creating a diagnostic analyzer (in python)

Tags: ros, python, tutorial, diagnostic-aggregator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everything works well until the last part Testing Analyzer.

I have this error : FAILURE: Test node [diagnostic_aggregator/analyzer_loader] does not exist or is not executable.
I can't understand my mistake.
Thank you.

Edit 1 : I can't reopen this subject (I don't have enough point for)  , but it seems that there is an issues in python, try to read the comment,
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185155/error-in-tutorial-creating-a-diagnostic-analyzer-(in-python)/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-07**:
did you do rosmake --pre-clean <package_name> ?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-07**:
It doesn't work
I still have the same error

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-07**:
did you do rosdep install  ? and then roscd takes you to the package..?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-07**:
roscd takes me to another folder : devel
So what is the issue?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-07**:
roscd  should take you to the package you are using

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-07**:
So what can I do?
I have just deleted everythink and redo the tutorials but I still have the same error

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-07**:
I tried on my PC running ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte, rosrun diagnostic_aggregator anlyzer_loader runs some program and that means that the executable exists for me. I am not sure what is causing you the problem that the `executable does not exist`

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-07**:
I am using groovy, does it change anythink?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-07**:
I do not think so

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-07**:
so what can I do?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-07**:
may be provide more information on what the steps you followed and 'exactly' the error that you got and wait till any one else answers it.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-08**:
I created the .h and .cpp file, then i changed the CmakeList as it is said in the tutorial,  I created the xml file and change the manifest.xml, and then i typed rosmake pr2_motors_analyzer and it says : Built 34 packages with 0 failures. (next just after)

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-08**:
(Next) Then I typed rospack plugins --attrib=plugin diagnostic_aggregator and it says : pr2_motors_analyzer /home/lempereur/catkin_ws/src/pr2_motors_analyzer/pr2_motors_analyzer_plugin.xml
diagnostic_aggregator /opt/ros/groovy/share/diagnostic_aggregator/analyzer_plugins.xml  (next just below)

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-08**:
And then I created the yaml file and the launch file, and when i typed the rostest command the error appears.
So can someone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect you don't have the diagnostic_aggregator package installed.

If you've using ROS Groovy on Ubuntu, you can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-diagnostic-aggregator
```

**EDIT**

This is a bug in the diagnostics package; I've filed it here: https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/issues/24

Until it's fixed, you should be able to complete the tutorial by checking the diagnostics package out from source and adding it to your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-10**:
Sorry but I don't understand what I have to do.
can you be more specific please?
Thank you

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-10**:
In the src folder of your catkin workspace, do

```
git clone https://github.com/ros/diagnostics.git
```

and then rebuild your workspace.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-10**:
It works!!!!
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) on 2014-07-14**:
it doesn't work for me. Roscd diagnostic_updater takes me to a directory under install isolated which doesn't have python libraries in it. I cannot import the diagnostic_updater package in my python code. I have asked the question on my account.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-15**:
I'm working in c++.
If you can, try to work in c++

**Comment by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) on 2014-07-15**:
I have some nodes or drivers that run in python. What do I do with them?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-16**:
@goshawk - please ask a new question with more specifics.

**Comment by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) on 2014-07-16**:
I got it to work by adding packages from source.